# Creating a perfect circle with 10px border that covers the entire screen but is completely contained in the viewport

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div and give it a `border-radius`.

So far I have:

```
<div style="height:100%;width:100%;border-radius:200%;border:10px solid 000;">---</div>
```

There are 2 problems with this:

1. The circle stretches based on the width of the web browser.
2. The border, which is 10px in this case, actually surpasses the browser's width.

My goal is to create a perfect circle within which I can design my entire site.

The circle always needs to re-size based on the browser, but should not become an oval shape, thus it should always be a perfect circle.

**UPDATE**

`border-radius:200%`

The above is simply a test. I am not certain what it should be, perhaps 50%

Comment: This sounds like it will make the webpage rather hard to read.

Comment: You mean like this?- http://jsfiddle.net/b7q7f/3/ or this - http://jsfiddle.net/3PrtV/1/

Comment: A piece of the answer is that : `{ Box-sizing: Border-box }` that will include padding and borders into the width (works on IE 8+). About the oval thing, that's even simpler. If you want to fill a rectangle with a circle, that's not possible... so obviously you should choose if you want to fill the height or the width, and most probably the answer will be the height as most people have their screen in landscape, not portrait.

Comment: @Paulie_D, looking good. will test it.

Comment: An easy way of implementing this type of design may be just around the corner - checkout adobes contributions to the upcoming standards regarding shapes and fitting text in and around them http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/shapes/

Comment: What about HTML5 canvas ?

Comment: The answer from Paulie_D via comment seems to be working ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a [combination of tricks](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units), we can not only keep the `div` a perfect circle, but center it in the viewport. First, however, we need to create a wrapper `div`:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="circular"><!-- content --></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100vh; /* viewport-height units */
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; /* for horizontal centering */
    position: relative; /* for vertical centering */
    top: 50%; /* for vertical centering */
}
.circular {
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 13% 13%; /* keep text within circle */
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid #000;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* so 100% width includes border */
    height: 100vw; /* viewport-width units */
    max-height: 100vh; /* viewport-height units */
    margin-top: -50%; /* for vertical centering */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NzGyV/